# Squaring a central sum of conjugate idempotents?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, idempotents

Suppose $G$ is a finite group. For a subgroup $K\leq G$, I define $e_K\in\mathbb{C}G$ to be the standard trivial idempotent $\frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{k\in K}k$.

Fixing a subgroup $H\leq G$, and putting 
$$
x=\sum_{g\in [G/N_G(H)]} e_{gHg^{-1}},
$$
where my notation denotes that the sum is over a complete set of coset representatives of $G/N_G(H)$, we get a central element in $\mathbb{C}G$.

My question, is this element idempotent, or close to it? (Perhaps something like $x^2=cx$ for some constant $c$?) For instance, if $H$ is normal, then $x=e_H$, which is idempotent. But generally, I don't see a reasonable way to square this sum if there is one.

Comment: Not sure if you're interested, but since $\mathbb C[G]$ is semisimple, *every* element is of the form $ue$ for a unit $u$ and an idempotent $e$. That's in the direction you're talking about, but $u$ could be some other unit, of course.

Comment: Looks like you might be rephrasing a comment that I just saw, but yes, semisimple rings have that property precisely because they are unit-regular.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks, I found that the equivalence is given as an exercise in Lam's book.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just try out a small example; I'm afraid you will find that your $x$ will be quite far from being idempotent.

In the smallest case, let $G=S_3$ and $H=\langle(1\;2)\rangle$. Then you have
$$\begin{align}x&=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\big((1\;2)+(1\;3)+(2\;3)\big)\text{, but}\\
x^2&=3+\frac{3}{2}\big((1\;2)+(1\;3)+(2\;3)\big)+\frac{3}{4}\big((1\;2\;3)+(1\;3\;2)\big)\end{align}$$